# How to programmatically generate config.xml from Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins has the ability to upload new jobs via its REST API.  Those new jobs require an XML document which, to the best of my searching, has no schema available.

When creating jobs as part of an SCM repo, you can include a `Jenkinsfile` and it automatically gets translated into a job with the `config.xml` filled out.

I tried creating a minimal `config.xml` and including the Jenkinsfile content in the `<script>…</script>` section of the xml file.  This works for trivial jobs, but does not work for jobs that have parameters:  The job gets uploaded as a parameterless job.  The first time you trigger a build of the job, it fails - but then the job turns into a job-with-parameters, and can properly be built.

How do I convert a `Jenkinsfile`, possibly with parameters or other "advanced" features, into a working `config.xml` file on the first try?  Or, alternatively, is it possible to directly upload the `Jenkinsfile` to the Jenkins REST API to create the job?

Thanks in advance,
— Johnson